# Google Map Geolocation Error

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am given the location (lat and long) but the location is not correct, the decimal point is not placed right. So, I was told to do the conversion with this code:

```
var location = "N1433.704483,E12100.012501";
var latlngarr = location[1].split(",");

if (latlngarr) {

    longitude = latlngarr[1]; //经度

    if (longitude.indexOf("E") >= 0) {

        longitude = longitude.substring(1);
        var degree = longitude / 100 | 0; //除100后取整。
        var cent = (longitude - degree * 100); //分的部分。
        longitude = degree + cent / 60.0;

    } else if (longitude.indexOf("W") >= 0) {

        longitude = longitude.substring(1);
        var degree = longitude / 100 | 0; //除100后取整。
        var cent = (longitude - degree * 100); //分的部分。
        longitude = degree + cent / 60.0;
    }

    latitude = latlngarr[0]; //纬度

    if (latitude.indexOf("N") >= 0) {

        latitude = latitude.substring(1);
        var degree = latitude / 100 | 0; //除100后取整。
        var cent = (latitude - degree * 100); //分的部分。
        latitude = degree + cent / 60.0;

    } else if (latitude.indexOf("S") >= 0) {

        latitude = latitude.substring(1);
        var degree = latitude / 100 | 0; //除100后取整。
        var cent = (latitude - degree * 100); //分的部分。
        latitude = degree + cent / 60.0;
    }
}
```

But when I try to put it inside my code the page says "Object Not Found!" Here is my full code.

```
var location = "N1433.704483,E12100.012501";
var latlngarr = location[1].split(",");

if (latlngarr) {

    longitude = latlngarr[1]; //经度

    if (longitude.indexOf("E") >= 0) {

        longitude = longitude.substring(1);
        var degree = longitude / 100 | 0; //除100后取整。
        var cent = (longitude - degree * 100); //分的部分。
        longitude = degree + cent / 60.0;

    } else if (longitude.indexOf("W") >= 0) {

        longitude = longitude.substring(1);
        var degree = longitude / 100 | 0; //除100后取整。
        var cent = (longitude - degree * 100); //分的部分。
        longitude = degree + cent / 60.0;
    }

    latitude = latlngarr[0]; //纬度

    if (latitude.indexOf("N") >= 0) {

        latitude = latitude.substring(1);
        var degree = latitude / 100 | 0; //除100后取整。
        var cent = (latitude - degree * 100); //分的部分。
        latitude = degree + cent / 60.0;

    } else if (latitude.indexOf("S") >= 0) {

        latitude = latitude.substring(1);
        var degree = latitude / 100 | 0; //除100后取整。
        var cent = (latitude - degree * 100); //分的部分。
        latitude = degree + cent / 60.0;
    }
}

var locations = [
    ['Bondi Beach', latitude, longitude],
    ];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(14.5833, 120.9667),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
        return function () {
            infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

location isn't an array, it is a string, so location[1] doesn't make sense.  "location" is a bad name for a variable, it tends to change the URL of the page in some browsers.

```
var location = "N1433.704483,E12100.012501";
var latlngarr = location[1].split(",");
```

should be:

```
var plocation = "N1433.704483,E12100.012501";
var latlngarr = plocation.split(",");
```